# Неправильная генерация символов

Tags: c#

```
// random symbol
Random r = new Random();

int x = 0;
int y = 1000;
string[] symb = new string[] {
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e",
    "f", "g", "x", "y", "z"
};

int num = r.Next(x,y);
string snum = Convert.ToString(num);
Console.WriteLine(snum);
string generate = "";
string[] gen = new string[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (snum.Contains(""+i)) {
        gen[i] = symb[i];
        generate += gen[i];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(generate);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Генерируется случайное число, затем оно дешифруется в набор символов. Например 675 будет равно "gxf". Но есть одна ошибка, из-за которой я и открываю данный вопрос, и вот в чем она заключается. Если цифры повторяются, то он их дешифрует как одну букву, например: 606 = "ez";
 Как записывать переменную, чтобы она записывала одинаковые буквы, а не удаляла одну из 2, которые были изначально.

Comment: какое-то странное кодирование строки, которое _не зависит_ от строки. Делай цикл по самой строке, и для каждого символа _из строки_ ищи нужный символ

Comment: Если не секрет зачем такое кодирование Вы делаете, какую цель преследуете?

Comment: судя по количеству букв - вы просто хотите заменить цифры буквами, причем одна и та же цифра всегда меняется на одну и ту же букву, я прав? Оставим в стороне вопрос зачем, спишем на "хочется".

Comment: @rdorn именно так

Comment: добавил ответ, разбирайтесь. Перемудрили вы слишком в своем решении, все гораздо проще на самом деле.

Comment: @rdorn я новичок в c# и нет источника нормального с информацией, так что учусь как могу и делаю так же. Спасибо за решение)

Comment: @smily_prg http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/198316 думаю тут найдете для себя подходящие источники. Ну и Скиенна, Кормен, Кнут (в порядке увеличения сложности и объема материала). Для совсем-совсем начала можно поискать задачник Шеня или порешать задачки с того-же Эйлера https://projecteuler.net/, К ним даже перевод энтузиасты сделали, гуглится легко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по количеству букв - вы просто хотите заменить цифры буквами, причем одна и та же цифра всегда меняется на одну и ту же букву.

Сначала поправим ошибку и уберем лишнее

```
while (num > 0)
{
    generate = symb[num % 10] + generate;
    num /= 10;
}
```

Этого достаточно чтобы разобрать число на цифры и собрать в строку нужные буквы. Замечу, не требуется превращать число в строку, цифры из него и без того легко извлекаются, правда собирать строку придется с конца.

Тут возможна небольшая оптимизация, которая в данном случае не слишком критична, но при более сложных задачах со строками - обязательна. Заменим тип переменной `generate` на `StringBuilder`:

```
var generate = new StringBuilder();
```

Тогда добавление символа в начало строки будет выглядеть так:

```
generate.Insert(0,symb[num % 10]);
```

Что это дает? Объекты `String` в .NET неизменяемы, а это значит, что при сцеплении строк образуется новая строка, а все не нужное ждет сборки мусора и занимает память. `StringBuilder` - представляет изменяемую строку, и при любых манипуляциях с ним новые объекты не создаются, а следовательно и не забивают память мусором. Это особенно важно когда вы генерируете длинную строку в цикле. В случае 3-4-значных чисел это разумеется не даст заметного выигрыша.

Также заменим

```
string[] symb = new string[] {
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e",
    "f", "g", "x", "y", "z"
};
```

на

```
string symb = "abcdefgxyz";
```

Остальной код можно не менять, к символам строки допустимо обращение по индексу `symb[i]`

Comment: Огромное спасибо